# Create a program that generate a Unity3D application

Tags: c, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a simple program that should create a Unity3D application. I read the Unity manual in the section of [Command line arguments](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) and I wrote a simple C program in which the user can choose the Operating System and execute some Unity command.
I tried to use the command to create a new project and build the application for a target device and I saw that it works.
Now I designed a 3D model by using Sketchup and I generate a .obj file to import it in Unity. I've to import this model in Unity by using command line arguments, but I don't know how I can import this .obj file.
Does anyone know how I can to solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't built from the command line, but Unity will auto import everything you put into the assets folder. Is this not the case with the command line?

Comment: don't expect every aspect of unity to be command line driven - only the build process has a command line for the rest use unity editor as usual

Comment: @Emile: so you suggest me to create use the command line tool to create a new project and put the 3D model in the asset folder and after that I've to run the command line tool to create the Unity app?

Comment: I'm making some assumptions about your question. Firstly when you say "make" i assume you mean build, i.e. make an executable. If you're thinking make a unity project, then its a much broader question.

Comment: If your asking how to import an image into your assets folder to use in your build process, then you might try out a couple of things. But you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this in the [Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetDatabase.html).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ImportAsset {
    [MenuItem ("AssetDatabase/ImportExample")]
    static void ImportExample ()
    {
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset("Assets/Textures/texture.jpg", ImportAssetOptions.Default);
    }
}
```

Massive assumption, especially given LearnCocos2D comment. **If** the commandline can run editor scripts, which this is one of, then you might be able to try the above out as a part of your build process.

Comment: So you suggest me to use this command: `-executeMethod` to call a method similar to this you posted on here

Comment: Yes, something like that, i'm afraid i haven't myself had to do this as my projects aren't structured this freely. I've so far manually created packages that i import into a unity project, rather than have them built automatically. This is certainly how i would explore the possibilities though.